# mudar função o carregamento de paginas jquery para o onclick

Tags: jquery

Eu estou querendo melhorar a forma de carregamento de páginas do meu projeto.

Neste projeto estou usando `jquery` para carregar a página dentro de um box quando clico em algum dos links que deixo disponíveis. Nesse script ele usa o link que está no `href` para carrega a página.

Só que eu gostaria (se for possível) 'maquiar' esse link com o `onclick`. Quero fazer com que se a pessoa clicar diretamente no link carregue a página no box que deve ser carregado, só que eu quero também se a pessoa quiser abrir aquele link em uma nova aba ela possa abrir, só que uma pagina diferente.

Ou seja, no `href` eu quero usar um link onde se a pessoa clicar pra abrir a pagina em nova aba vai abrir por exemplo a pagina a.php, agora se a pessoa clicar direto no link carregue a pagina b.php via `jquery` dentro do box.

O script que `jquery` que uso para o carregamento das paginas dentro do box é:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     $('.postss a').live('click',function(){
           $('#conteudo').load($(this).attr('href')); 
           return false; 
     });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se eu entendi o que você quer, pode criar um novo atributo para isso

```
<a href="a.php" out-href="b.php">Link label</a>
```

Então muda o seu código para:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     $('.postss a').live('click',function(){
           $('#conteudo').load($(this).attr('href')); 
           window.open($(this).attr('out-href'), 'nova janela'); 
           return false; 
     });
});
```

Comment: Entendi a linha de raciocínio. Eu só não usei o out-href, utilizei um id, assim substitui o attr('href') pelo attr('id'). E no link adicionei o id, ai ficou <a href="a.php" id="b.php">Link</a>

Comment: Esse atributo out-href não é padrão do HTML, então pode ser "criado" para suas necessidades, acho arriscado usar um atributo existente para um contexto diferente, principalmente id, mas se pegou o raciocínio ótimo

Comment: Como o @Jader comentou em sua resposta, mude a linha onde pega o elemento, ao invés de usar .live use .on: `$('.postss a').on('click', null, function(){`

Answer (score 0):

Tem uma maneira de fazer sem ter que modificar os links nas paginas:

**jquery:**

```
function jaw_href(href, parametros) { return encodeURI(href.replace(/#*/g,'') + (href.indexOf('?') != -1 ? "&" : "?") + parametros); }

$(document).ready(function() {

$("body").on("click", ".postss a", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#conteudo').load( jaw_href($(this).attr("href"), "ajax=true") ); 
});

});
```

Obs.: Criei a função `jaw_href` para adicionar o parâmetro no final da URI, caso já tenha parâmetros concatena com `&` do contrario com `?`.

Então basta verificar a variável `$_GET['ajax']` e se necessário aplicar modificações para requisições ajax.

Quando o usuario mandar abrir em nova aba, ou segurar o ctrl e clicar no link, vai abrir o link original sem `ajax=true`.

**Atenção para a função `.live()` ela foi obsoleta e foi removida no jquery 1.9+**